# Django Database Query Optimisation with iterator() in templates

Tags: python, django, optimization, iterator

There are several rules on how to Optimise Database Queries in Django. One of them is [`iterator()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.iterator). Does it make sense to use `iterator` in templates(HTML files)? Or when I loop in the template with `for` statement it is already an iterator and no additional optimization is needed?

Example:

```
{% for item in items.all%}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

VS

```
{% for item in items.all.iterator %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**
The query runs often, so basic caching is needed.

Comment: `.iterator(..)` is useful to reduce the memory footprint. But for several queries it will result in slower queries, it will drop `.prefetch_related` and `.select_related`s as well.

Comment: I do understand how it works in python modules, but templates might have different optimization logic.

Comment: no, in fact the template engine does not alter the calls, or anything. It simply translate it to function calls, but it is "oblivious" of the logic.

Comment: It is however advisable to write the business logic in the view, templates are only meant to render the business logic correctly.

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks

Comment: Willem if you write all listed above in the main answer field I accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comments to the question I decided to summarize everything in a full answer.

Django Templates are linked to Views and so it is the same optimization logic with `iterator` as in general Python modules.

There is no optimization in the example below as the View and the Template are used often. Even worth: there is no db queries caching in such case.

```
{% for item in items.all.iterator %}
    {{ item.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Best practices are to put main business logic in the views. So you should put `items.all()` in the view and use only `items` in the template.

There are not many good examples when to use `iterator()`. Mainly there is a sentence that you should use `iterator()` if you call query once. I would say that you should use `iterator()` when query calls are not often. For example, if you sold some item in your web store and generated a `ThankYou` page. You may show in "thank you" page the order and items that are in the order. In such case the query is quite unique and doesn't call often and might be called only once. Also, no caching is needed for the future requests on "thank you" page with the order info.